# Google Vision API Text Detection Display Words by Block

Tags: node.js, express, google-vision

Is there a way to group the text response of Google's Document Text Detection API by block? I may have overlooked it in the documentation if ever there is a provided solution. I am currently using node.js to get the text from the image provided by the user. Here is my code:

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({
  keyFilename: 'APIKey.json'
});
client
  .documentTextDetection('image.jpg')
  .then(results => {
    res.send(results);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.send(err);
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a standardized way to do this, but the Vision API does give us everything we need to compose the block text, including relevant breaks (see [Vision API break Types](http://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/grpc-google-cloud-vision-v1/0.1.5/apidocs/com/google/cloud/vision/v1/TextAnnotation.DetectedBreak.BreakType.html)). So we can enumerate each block and create the text from it.

There are a couple of other break types I'm not accounting for (HYPHEN, SURE_SPACE), but I think it should be easy to add these.

For example:

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({
    keyFilename: 'APIKey.json'
});

client
.documentTextDetection('image.jpg')
.then(results => {
    console.log("Text blocks: ", getTextBlocks(results));
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error("An error occurred: ", err);
});

function getTextBlocks(visionResults) {
    let textBlocks = [];
    let blockIndex = 0;;
    visionResults.forEach(result => {
        result.fullTextAnnotation.pages.forEach(page => {
            textBlocks = textBlocks.concat(page.blocks.map(block => { return { blockIndex: blockIndex++, text: getBlockText(block) }}));
        });
    });
    return textBlocks;
}

function getBlockText(block) {
    let result = '';
    block.paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
        paragraph.words.forEach(word => {
            word.symbols.forEach(symbol => {
                result += symbol.text;
                if (symbol.property && symbol.property.detectedBreak) {
                    const breakType = symbol.property.detectedBreak.type;
                    if (['EOL_SURE_SPACE' ,'SPACE'].includes(breakType)) {
                        result += " ";
                    }
                    if (['EOL_SURE_SPACE' ,'LINE_BREAK'].includes(breakType)) {
                        result += "\n"; // Perhaps use os.EOL for correctness.
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am getting an error message of the following:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectedBreak' of null

Comment: Apparently, symbol.property can also be null, so:
if(symbol.property) before anything else. Thanks!

Comment: @TerryLennox can you do this in php please?

Comment: Sure thing @overflow-stack.. it'll be slightly different... could you ask a question, I think it would be better to create a new question for this?

Comment: @TerryLennox can you try solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817740/how-can-i-detect-all-the-text-that-inside-a-block-with-google-vision-api/57818828#57818828

Comment: @TerryLennox, good day to you, have you viewed the question yet?